# Duplicate values being returned from JSON MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to put together a statistics page that displays the highest value of each unit type along with the user id of the user who has the highest value of the unit type. However my code is outputting duplicate values for the unit types which is not what in need. The data is stored in a mysql database in a JSON string, the user id is stored in a separate column. Below is a sample of my JSON, Code, and the current output

```
[{"locoType":"C44Dash9W","totalLocoHrs":20.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875},{"locoType":"GP402","totalLocoHrs":1000.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625}][{"locoType":"C44Dash9W","totalLocoHrs":17.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125},{"locoType":"GP402","totalLocoHrs":2},{"locoType":"ES44","totalLocoHrs":6.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125},{"locoType":"SD70ACE","totalLocoHrs":4.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625},{"locoType":"SD402","totalLocoHrs":2.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375},{"locoType":"Hyrailer01","totalLocoHrs":0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125},{"locoType":"P42","totalLocoHrs":0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125},{"locoType":"TrackMobile","totalLocoHrs":2.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375}][{"locoType":"SD452","totalLocoHrs":15.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875},{"locoType":"GP402","totalLocoHrs":17.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625},{"locoType":"ES44","totalLocoHrs":19.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875},{"locoType":"SD70ACE","totalLocoHrs":4.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125},{"locoType":"C44Dash9W","totalLocoHrs":29.60000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625},{"locoType":"SD402","totalLocoHrs":7.5},{"locoType":"TrackMobile","totalLocoHrs":1.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125}]
```

````
// Query the database to get the locoData for each user
$sql = "SELECT uid, locoData FROM data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Create an empty array to store the highest values for each locoType
$highest_values = array();

// Iterate through each user's locoData and update the highest values array
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_id = $row["uid"];
        $loco_data = json_decode($row["locoData"], true);
        foreach ($loco_data as $loco_type => $total_hours) {
    if (!isset($highest_values[$loco_type]) || $total_hours > $highest_values[$loco_type]['totalLocoHrs']) {
        $highest_values[$loco_type] = array('totalLocoHrs' => $total_hours, 'uid' => $user_id, 'locoType' => $loco_type);
    }
}
    }
}

// $highest_values should now contain the highest value for each locoType across all users in the database
//print_r($highest_values);
echo "<table>";
echo "<th>Type</th><th>Hrs</th><th>UID</th>";
foreach ($highest_values as $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $value['totalLocoHrs']['locoType'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value['totalLocoHrs']['totalLocoHrs'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value['uid'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

// Close the database connection
$conn->close();```


Type    Hrs UID
SD452   15.2    14
GP402   1000.9  12
ES44    19.2    14
SD70ACE 4.4     13  
SD402   2.4     13  
SD402   7.5     14
TrackMobile 1.3 14
TrackMobile 2.9 13
````

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is the problem;

```
SELECT uid, locoData FROM data
```

*Probably* should be something like;

```
SELECT uid, locoData FROM data GROUP BY loco_type
```

But it looks like you're doing some crazy stuff with JSON from your example. MySQL 8+ does support more complex JSON querying through raw SQL queries so you may want to look at that.

Your MySQL Query is returning multiple rows, then your script is trying to parse and interpret that data. You need to get MySQL to do the heavy lifting, not your script.

Get back to basics. Just get the data right with your SQL Query in MySQL Workbench. Once you get that right, put it into code.